# Outlook macro icon click event

Tags: vba, events, outlook, click, icons

I have a subroutine assigned to a button on the ribbon. All it does is show a form I'm using to simplify some email processing I need to do. This is a constant work in progress so I added a message box in the form's initialization asking if this is live or not. That changes colors and some functionality to help my testing.

I don't want to have to answer that message box every time I use it (sometimes 30 or 40 times a day) but I still want a clean way to get into my testing mode. I'd like to shift-click or ctrl-click the ribbon icon or something like that to trigger my testing mode.

The public sub is in a module that just shows the form.

```
Public Sub RunAutoReply()
    frmAutoReply.Show
End Sub
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm on MS Office Pro Plus 2016.

Comment: Put a Global boolean DEBUG variable in your VBProject which can be checked by the form when it opens - if `True` then have your code skip the messagebox.  You can use another button to toggle the value of that global.

Comment: Wouldn't that involve opening the VBA code to manually set the flag? I know that will work but I was looking more to see if my VBA script could detect the use of a keyboard modifier like the Shift key when the icon is clicked on the ribbon. I could also create another Sub that sets the flag and add that to the ribbon but this is just as much an exercise in seeing if it can be done as adding the functionality.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx

Comment: Tim, sorry. I just reread your response and said exactly what you suggested. You're right. Here's what I did. I created a global Boolean and a new sub. I set the Boolean based off the sub selected and use the Property Get in the form to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

I though I knew what was asked until I read the comments in the question.

This could demo the concept.

```
Option Explicit

' Choose a name almost impossible to be used elsewhere.
Public testMode_for_RunAutoReply_unique As Boolean
'

Public Sub toggle_testMode_for_RunAutoReply()

    testMode_for_RunAutoReply_unique = Not testMode_for_RunAutoReply_unique

    If testMode_for_RunAutoReply_unique = True Then
        Debug.Print "In test mode"

    Else
        Debug.Print "In live mode."

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub RunAutoReply()

    If testMode_for_RunAutoReply_unique = True Then
        Debug.Print "Safe to test."

    Else
        Debug.Print "Live!"

    End If

End Sub
```